# Защита софта с помощью программы Guardant

Tags: безопасность

Наша компания для работы приобретает весьма стоит проблема   защиты от взлома и нелицензированного копирования ПО и информации, причем не только со стороны, но и от "своих дураков". В этой связи вопрос: на сколько хороша в этом деле программа Guardant? Было бы интересно мнение людей, которые работали с ней или с аналогичными программами.

Comment: Вообще-то не совсем по теме этого форума вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Как меня бесят эти ключи. Есть лицензия на одну програмулину, но пользуемся ломанной так как то драйвер на ключик не встанет, то прога его не видит... Хаспы чуть лучше, но тоже не удобны пользователю, да и эмуляторы уже есть. По мне так лучше велосипед на эцп или привязку к флешке(обычной)

Comment: "Наша компания для работы приобретает весьма стоит проблема защиты от взлома" -  Чё?

Answer (score 0):

В принципе Guardant довольно надежен. По сути это то же ЭЦП с аппаратным ключом. Может работать и на винде, и на линуксе. В отличие от аналогичных систем у этой русифицированный софт, что тоже удобно. Правда, флешки есть флешки и с ними своя неудобь и косяки. Но, как  верно сказал коллега, есть уже и эмуляторы.